# Wordpress issue with database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, security, server

I've been working on a website and suddenly I get this error:

Error establishing a database connection

I was in contact with the host about the issue and they have blocked our connection with modsys due to a  script in our installation.

They want us to remove scripts containing e.x

```
mysql_connect($_POST['dbhost'], $_POST['dbuser'], $_POST['dbpass']);
mysql_select_db($_POST['dbname']);
```

I can't seem to find this anywhere, the theme is deactivated and all plugins are deactivated.

Comment: Deactivating themes and plugins doesn't remove them from the server. If they are scanning your files for sql injection risks they'll still see them even if you disable them. A plugin/theme using code like that is pretty scary though.

Comment: So my best bet would be to remove the plugins totally from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to download Notepad++ (windows) download your entire WordPress folder via ftp to your local machine. Use Notepad++ search in files facility to search through all the text contained within all the files - this will take some time but if that code sample is there Notepad++ will find it. Then you will know where it is and what its connected to so you can identify what aspect to remove (theme, plugin etc or malicious code).